# RobotFramework: Global variables which change only locally

Tags: variables, global-variables, robotframework

In the root of the test directory, I have this `setting.robot` file which includes the global variables used in all test suites and test cases. This file has been used as `resource` in all test cases:

```
*** Variables ***
${Variable1}       value1
${Variable2}       value2
${Variable3}       value3
${Variable4}       value4
...
```

Now suppose this is the test hierarchy I have:

> -- Suite1
>   ------ Test1
>   ------ Test2
>   -- Suite2
>   ------ Test3
>   ------ Test4

I might need to change the value of `${Variable1}` in `Test1`, so in the `setup` of `Test1` I use this code:

```
Set Global Variable    ${Variable1}    NewValue
```

The problem with this approach is the I am changing the value globally, and this will affect the other tests. Another solution is to use `Set Variable`:

```
${Variable1}=    Set Variable    NewValue
```

The problem with this method is that this variable change does not affect the lower level `user keywords`:

> Prior to Robot Framework 2.9 variables in the local scope leaked to
>   lower level user keywords. This was never an intended feature, and
>   variables should be set or passed explicitly also with earlier
>   versions.

So how can I have global variables which can be changed per test case when needed without affecting other tests?

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the variables to the keyword? (`variables should be set or passed explicitly`) It is a very good coding practice anyway. Using globals in functions is fragile.

Comment: @jim Because there are large number of variables. Maybe I should use [Variable Files](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.1.3/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files)

Comment: As I understand, the scope of the variable is only for that Test case. Have you tried 'Set Test Variable' keyword. It will be effective only for that test case and thel lower level user keywords in that test case.

Comment: have you triied "set suite variable"?